# Javascript toggle button fired uncontrollable on different device

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, browser, leaflet

I created a toggle button using Leaflet and jQuery with 2 functions:

- **First** : show croshair on the center of screen.
- **Second** : mark a location on the center of the map screen.

### Button code

```
L.Control.STARTpointroute = L.Control.extend({
            options: {
            position: 'topright'
            },
            initialize: function(options) {
            L.Util.setOptions(this, options);
            },
            
     //BEGIN create button using DOM
            onAdd: function() {
              this._map = mymap;
              var className = 'leaflet-control-startpoint',
              container = this._container = L.DomUtil.create('div', className);
              L.DomEvent.disableClickPropagation(container);
              var button = this._button = L.DomUtil.create('button', className );
    
              var showcrosshair = L.DomUtil.create('span', 'when-inactive');
              showcrosshair.textContent ='Pilih Lokasi Awal Rute';
              button.appendChild(showcrosshair);
    
              var marklocation = L.DomUtil.create('span', 'when-active');
              marklocation.textContent ='Okay';
              button.appendChild(marklocation);
     //END create button using DOM
              
     //BEGIN create toggle function using jquery
              $(function(){
                $('button.leaflet-control-startpoint').one('click', handler1);
                $('button.leaflet-control-startpoint').one("click", _crosshair);
                });
              
              function handler1() {
                $(this).addClass("active");    
                $(this).on("click", handler2);
                $(this).on("click", _marker);
                $(this).off("click", _crosshair);
              }
        
              function handler2() {
                $(this).removeClass("active");
                $(this).on("click", handler1);
                $(this).on("click", _crosshair);
                $(this).off("click", _marker);
              }
      //END create toggle function using jquery
              
      //BEGIN showing crosshair function
              _crosshair = function() {
                lc.stop();
                if (mymap.hasLayer(shortest_path )) {
                  mymap.removeLayer(shadowshortest_path);
                  mymap.removeLayer(shortest_path);}
                if (mymap.hasLayer(startMarker)) {
                  mymap.removeLayer(startMarker);
                  startMarker = undefined;}  
    
                var crosshairIcon = L.icon({
                  iconUrl: 'img/crosshair.png',
                  iconAnchor:   [75, 125]
                });
                crosshair =  L.marker(mymap.getCenter(), {icon: crosshairIcon, clickable:false});
                crosshair.addTo(mymap);

                mymap.on('move', function(e) {
                  crosshair.setLatLng(mymap.getCenter());
                });
              }
      //END showing crosshair function
              
      //BEGIN mark a center location
              _marker = function() {
                lc.stop();
                //menghilangkan tanda crosshair
                if (crosshair != null) {
                  mymap.removeLayer(crosshair);}
                
                //menambahkan marker lokasi awal rute
                startMarker = L.marker(mymap.getCenter(),
                              {icon : L.icon( iconstartMarker )});
                startMarker.addTo(mymap);
              }
      //END mark a center location
        
              container.appendChild(button);
              return button;
            }
          });

          var startPointRoute = new L.Control.STARTpointroute();
          mymap.addControl(startPointRoute);
```

I tried to execute the website on different devices in inspect element (google chrome).

In this device list, button can operate properly as I expected:

1. Galaxy S5
2. LG optimus L70
3. microsoft lumia 550 and 950
4. moto G4
5. nexus 10, 5, 4, and 7

And in this device list, the button fired uncontrolable with just one click (mostly clicked twice and sometimes thrice)

1. Blackbery Z30
2. Blackberry Playbook
3. Galaxy Note 3
4. Galaxy note II
5. Galaxy SIII
6. Kindle Fire HDX

Can it affect when I host on the web? does anyone have any tips for me?

Answer (score -1):

when i check all device release year, the button not gonna work in device before 2013.
i add touchend event

```
    $(function(){
         $('button.leaflet-control-startpoint').on("click touchend", handler1);
         $('button.leaflet-control-startpoint').on("click touchend", _crosshair);
                    });
    function handler1() {
         $(this).addClass("active");    
         $(this).on("click touchend", handler2);
         $(this).on("click touchend", _marker);
         $(this).off("click touchend", _crosshair);
                  }
    function handler2() {
         $(this).removeClass("active");
         $(this).on("click touchend", handler1);
         $(this).on("click touchend", _crosshair);
         $(this).off("click touchend", _marker);
                  }
```

but it's abit laggy